# jackson xml node with attribute to json

Tags: json, xml, jackson, attributes, transform

When try to trasform xml to json with jackson 2.12.7 (XMLMapper and ObjectMapper) have a problem with elements with attributes.

```
JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
```

From xml:

```
<Address><Province Code="MI">MILAN</Province></Address>
```

obtain this json:

```
{"Province":{"Code":"MI","":"MILAN"}}
```

**"":"MILAN"**

How to set a default tag name when this is empty (es: "Value" or "City" etc etc)?

Comment: There are some similar questions on SO, I think you can do it changing your xml a little:
EX: <Province Code="MI" City="MILAN"></Province>
OR
<Province Code="MI"><City>MILAN</City></Province>

Comment: Can't change xml